# MySql query ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Here is my data. I want to take 6 rows, but I want all `HeadlineCategoryId`'s to be unique in my result list. If I select the top 6 I would take 2 rows from `HeadlineCategoryID` 20  (6,2).  Do you have any suggestions about it?

Comment: which server really are you using? mysql or sql server? if you take top 6 it will return two `20`, what record you want to get? `2` or `6`?

Comment: @JW웃 as you can understand my question's title I use MySql... I don't want get 2 records of 20.

Comment: what determines which newsid/creation you want for the duplicate headlinecategoryids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  HeadlineCategoryID, MAX(Creation) max_date
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY HeadlineCategoryID
        ) b ON  a.HeadlineCategoryID = b.HeadlineCategoryID AND
                a.Creation = b.max_date
ORDER   BY a.Creation DESC  -- << specify here how are you going to sort
LIMIT   6                   --    the records you want to get
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  HeadlineCategoryID, MAX(NewsID) max_id
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY HeadlineCategoryID
        ) b ON  a.HeadlineCategoryID = b.HeadlineCategoryID AND
                a.NewsID = b.max_id
ORDER   BY a.Creation DESC  -- << specify here how are you going to sort
LIMIT   6                   --    the records you want to get
```

Comment: I tired your query too but it is the same result with Gordon's answer.

Comment: because `Creation` is the same, try changing it with `NewdID`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the six most recent records, but unique by HeadlineCategoryId.  If so, this will work:

```
select top 6 NewsId, Creation, HeadlineCategoryId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by HeadlineCategoryId order by Creation desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

As a note . . . This question originally indicated that it was using SQL Server, not MySQL.  The solution in MySQL is not as simple.  Here is one method with `not exists`:

```
select NewsId, Creation, HeadlineCategoryId
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.HeadlineCategoryId = t.HeadlineCategoryId and
                        t2.id < t.id)
limit 6
```

The `not exists` portion is saying "where there is no other record with a larger id for a given headline category".

Comment: It gives 6 records but 20 has 2 records still.

Comment: the creation times for the dups are the same